# Good real analysis text in Italian

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I am searching for a good introductory real analysis text in Italian, something which can parallel "Real Analysis" of Royden in clarity if not in scope, concise and to the point, with nice exercises and counterexamples.

Comment: I haven't had a closer look, but the multi-volume work by Giaquinta and Modica seems quite impressive. Here a link to the english translation of one of the books: https://books.google.de/books?id=0YE_AAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Thank you; it looks that they introduce the Lebesgue integral only in the fourth volume (which you gave the link to). And unfortunately, I could not find the contents of the first volume online to make a better judgement.

Comment: This should be the first volume: https://books.google.de/books?id=rHvkBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: thank you for the link.